# Check files in Amazon-s3 before uploading

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, gulp, knox-amazon-s3-client

So I set up a module that allows me to upload files to amazon-s3. The problem is there is no way I can check for upload overwrite. Ideally, I want to go into amazon-s3 first and check if the file I want to upload exist or not and then stop the upload if it does. Is there anyway I could do that?